# How to execute the multiple commands with && operator in new lines(not all in single line) :shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am Installing multiple packages by using && operator for stopping execution of succeeding one if preceding one fails. && function is working when all written in single line.

But When they written in line by line && function is not working and I am getting error.
My code is like this:

```
yum -y install XXZ \
&& yum -y install rsync \
&& yum -y install libxml2-devel \
&& yum -y install ntp
```

The Error is:

```
install5.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
'nstall5.sh: line 4: `&& yum -y install rsync \
```

How to stop the execution of successive one if preceding one fails by using && operator when the commands are written in line by line(not in a single line).?

Please Help!

Comment: The && syntax simply tests that the exit code of the previous command is 0 before proceeding to the next. The same can be achieved by testing the status of $? in an if statement.

Comment: I think it just wants `yum -y install XXZ rsync libxml2-devel ntp`. If you want to break it up, you can use *line-continuations* (e.g. `'\'`) but do not put additional `&& yum -y install` in there. Or if you want the next install conditioned on a successful install of the previous, then I would put `&&` at the **end** of the lines and get rid of the `'\'`. `yum` is also smart enough to know when an install fails and it will stop the install for you.

Comment: Thank u @David C. Rankin. If I remove '\' Then also && function is not working. Successive one is working even if preceding one fails. And i just want to stop the execution of successive one if preceding one fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$? stores exit code of last command. You can do the following in a script:

```
yum -y install XXZ
if [[ $? != "0" ]]   ## exit code other than zero 
then
    ## your code for failure
    exit
fi
yum -y install rsync
if [[ $? != "0" ]]     
then
    ## your code for failure
    exit
fi
```

Do the same for all packages.
I recommend you to make an array and use for loop.
Exit code zero means success. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks Neel_123. But i am getting error                                      
install5.sh: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file                                                                  The code is:                                                                                         yum -y install XXZ
if [[ $? != "0" ]];
then
exit
else
echo 'success'

Comment: bash waits for if to complete. Add fi at the end of the script

Comment: @Nell_123 I have added.still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Unexpected End Of File means bash is waiting for some command to end but it encountered end of your script. Try checking for loops  which need an "done" in the end or some missing "fi" for an "if". Can you post the script itself?

Comment: yum -y install rsync;
if ($? -eq 0 ); then
echo 'success'
else 
echo 'fail'
fi

Comment: @Nell_123 Error is:                                                                      
 install5.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
'nstall5.sh: line 18: `else

Comment: Again bash waits for something and encounters else. Can you kindly copy the lines of code in the answer in a new script and run it as it is and tell me the output.

Comment: The error is:                                                                                                install5.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
                                                                                                 
'nstall5.sh: line 9: `if [[ $? != "0" ]]

Comment: @ Nell_123 I add the semicolon end of the if statement. Now the Error is:          install5.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: There are no syntax errors in the script. Are you using bash shell or some other?

Comment: I am saving the script with "install.sh".(.sh). So it is bash shell scripiting.

Comment: No That is not necessary. add `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script

Comment: I Have added that too.still Getting like that only. And i also run the simple program using if. Then also getting same error.

Comment: What is that simple program?

Comment: a=10
b=20
if [ $a == $b ] 
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi

Comment: there are no bugs in shell. Try this `if date; then echo hi; fi`

Comment: Still same Error Neel.                                                                    
install5.sh: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: okay....! remove all the spaces following the last "fi". and preceding first "if" and execute again. What distro are you using? And how can it be on line 5. Make it the first and last line of the file

Comment: I am using Note Pad++. The code executed when written in single line.  
 And got the same error when written in line by line.

Comment: Neel Program executed..I added the semicolon after the 'f'i also.The It worked fine.Thank you So much for your efforts.

Comment: If the script worked successfully then mark the question as solved and like the answer :p

Comment: Neel Can You give syntax and logic for the (for loop).The successive one should not execute if the preceding one fails.

Comment: an example:   array=( one two three )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
 echo $i
done

Answer (score 0):

```
yum -y install XXZ &&
yum -y install rsync &&
yum -y install libxml2-devel && 
yum -y install ntp
```

or

```
yum -y install XXZ && \
yum -y install rsync && \
yum -y install libxml2-devel && \ 
yum -y install ntp
```

I am Using NotePad++. After modifying the EOL Conversion from windows to format to UNIX\OSX. The above code is executed.
Edit --> EOL Conversion --> UNIX\OSX format. and save the document.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other solutions, you could also use:

```
if ! yum -y install XXZ ; then
    # command failed, do what you want
    exit
fi
if ! yum -y install rsync ; then
    # command failed, do what you want
    exit
fi
```

etc.